# \date does not work

Tags: date

I've got this .tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{here}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\fancyhf{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{name \date{\today}}
\lfoot{lecture, WS 2016/2017}
\rfoot{problem sheet no 2} 

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

But the Point is that the date isn't displayed anywhere?

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: Welcome, leave out the outer `\date` and use *just* `\today`.

Comment: `\date` *saves* a date for reuse with `\maketitle`.

Comment: As Johannes say. The command `\date` is primarily used to specify which date `\maketitle` should print, so it does nothing useful here.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- I think you have the answer for this one.

Comment: @jon This gotta be a duplicate, let me look for it.